# Convert Excel time and date to Unix Epoch time

Tags: excel-formula

I have two cells - one with a date and one with a time.

The date cell A1 is formatted as Cell Type Date MM/DD/YY. 
The time cell B1 is formatted as Cell Type Time HH:00 AM/PM.

I am able to combine the cells using the formula TEXT(A1,"m/dd/yy ")&TEXT(B1,"h:mm AM/PM") with the result in cell C1.

For another program, I need to convert the date and time to Unix Epoch format and subtract the combined cell from 1/1/1970 (cell D1).

However, the formula (C1-D1)*86400 is not working. The formula gives a #VALUE error.

I understand the combined date and time has been converted to text so I set the cell format to the appropriate date and time format but that did not work either.

What's the appropriate procedure for performing this action?

Answer (score 0):

Since dates are represented as integers and times are values between 0 and 1, you can combine column A and column B with simple addition and then format the cell appropriately.

[image: DateTime]

Then do as you suggested and take the difference from that date to 1/1/1970 and multiply by 86,400 seconds in a day to get the Unix Epoch time.

[image: Unix Epch]

---

Note: I accidentally put 8**8**6400 instead of 86400 in my screenshot. Please use the correct value.

Comment: When I use the formula A1+B1, I get a #VALUE error. It looks as if the time cell is causing the problem. I can seem to subtract the 1/1/1970 from the 1/31/2018 cell and get a number. Any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: @JD_99 Maybe the time cell isn't actually a number between 0 and 1. Can you check that? If it's text, then you can wrap it with a `TIMEVALUE` function.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check that per say. I did setup a dummy cell with the formula '= timevalue(B1)' but I still had the same #VALUE error.

Comment: @JD_99 If you try to change the format of that cell to number or currency, does anything happen?

Comment: getting the same error. I tried to copy and paste as values to another dummy cell and format it with number/currency also but it did not work.

Comment: Try this for me `CELL("format",B1)`. What does that return? Reference: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf Also try `B1+0` and `B1&""` and let me know if those return anything.

Comment: With cell format set as number, it returns F2, #VALUE, #VALUE respectively. With cell format set as currency, it returns C2, #VALUE, #VALUE respectively.